# In Visual Studio, How to look up all the tools controls elements that are in the form?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Quick question. Let's say I have 1000+ elements in my wpf application (Buttons, Images, Textblocks... etc) where each has a name and some settings. So my Xaml is huge. Now I want to find an element by name where I can't remember the exact name of this element. And in the GUI, this element's *Visibility* is `Hidden`.

Is there a list somewhere that I can **look up *All* the elements that are in my form**?

Comment: @leppie I imagine this would be provided by Visual Studio so that is why I added the tag

Comment: You are not writing code for VS, it is simply a tool you use.

Comment: @leppie So this is off topic on SO because I am looking for a tool?

Comment: No, but tagging a question with VS it means you are writing code for a VS plugin normally or some other part of it.

Comment: @leppie: `visual-studio` is a correct tag. IMO. He asked a question related specifically to the tool, not the programming.
Questions related to visual studio extensibility could be marked with both, `visual-studio` and `vs-extensibility` tags

Comment: I imagine so, same as @Liero. This should be tagged with `visual-studio` stuff

Comment: In that case, tag with CPU, OS ver, font family, etc... Get my point?

Comment: @leppie "_Visual Studio is an integrated development environment (IDE) from Microsoft. Do not use this tag unless you have a specific question about Visual Studio -- not just a coding issue._" SO says not just coding issue.

Comment: It is a specific question about tools available in Visual Studio, which makes the tag appropriate. If it was about extending Visual Studio, you wouldn't even use [tag:visual-studio], you'd use [tag:vs-extensibility] or [tag:visual-studio-extensions].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Document outline**

   There is a Document Outline tool window in Visual Studio, which is basically visual  representaion of you xaml tree:
   [image: document outline]
2. **Live Visual Tree**

   when you run an application, you can select and inspect any element you using Live Visual Tree tool. This is especially useful when you don't know in which usercontrol is the element you are looking for.

   [image]
3. **Split your view into multiple usercontrols**.

   Single responsibility principle also applies to UI views. For example create usercontrol for Header, another for Footer, you can extract each tab from tabcontrol into separate usercontrol, etc

Comment: Option 1 showed me what I needed to see and here is how I found it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46xf4h0w(v=vs.90).aspx